# Scatter plot with custom ticks

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I want to do a scatter plot of a wavelength (float) in y-axis and spectral class (list of character/string) in x-axis, labels = ['B','A','F','G','K','M']. Data are saved in pandas dataframe, df.

```
df['Spec Type Index']
0      NaN
1        A
2        G
.        .
.        .
167      K
168    Nan
169      G
```

Then,

```
df['Disk Major Axis &quot;']
0        4.30
1        4.50
2       22.00
.         .
.         .
167      1.32
168      0.28
169     25.00
```

Thus, I thought this should be done simply with

```
plt.scatter(df['Spec Type Index'], df['Disk Major Axis &quot;'])
```

But I get this annoying error

> could not convert string to float: 'G'

After fixing this, I want to make custom xticks as follows. However, how can I

```
labels = ['B','A','F','G','K','M']
ticks = np.arange(len(labels))
plt.xticks(ticks, labels)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think you have to map those strings to integers then matplotlib can decide where to place those points.

```
labels = ['B','A','F','G','K','M']
mapping = {'B': 0,'A': 1,'F': 2,'G': 3,'K': 4,'M': 5}
df = df.replace({'Spec Type Index': mapping})
```

Then plot the scatter,

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(df['Spec Type Index'], df['Disk Major Axis &quot;'])
```

Finally,

```
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
```